# SQL: Get the beginning date of the month from a Month_year name column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a date data as below:

```
 Monthyear
    Jan 2018
    Feb 2018
    Mar 2018
```

I want to convert this into this format:

```
Monthyear
01-01-2018
01-02-2018
01-03-2018
```

That is, as a date with the first date of the month.

I tried casting the above and it doesnt work.
Kindly help me out.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date):

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('1 ', Monthyear), '%e %b %Y')
```

e.g.

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('1 ', 'Jan 2018'), '%e %b %Y')
```

Output:

```
2018-01-01
```

The reason for `CONCAT`ing a `'1 '` to the string is to avoid issues with SQL `NO_ZERO_DATE` mode (this is discussed in the manual entry for `STR_TO_DATE`).

Comment: unfortunately it is not a recognized built-in function

Comment: I thought you were using MySQL?

Comment: i am but there are a few restrictions when i use openquery in my DB.

Comment: @SPishere openquery is an **MS SQL** product as far as I know? In which case you would need `CONVERT(DATETIME, Monthyear)`

Answer (score 2):

use `str_to_date()`

```
select str_to_Date(concat('01',Monthyear),"%d %b %Y")
```